# Scrapy - best way to export/store items in REST API

Tags: python, scrapy

What is the best way to export/store items in **REST API** ?

I want send scraped items to REST API, where should I put my 
requests.post(...) ?  Any examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Rubber duck debugging, propably simple pipeline with `process_item()` method, earlier I thought only about `Exporters` and `FeedStorage`